# Переменная не очищается

Tags: javascript, jquery

В subels пункты li накапливаются с каждой итерацией и не отчищаются при объявлении, а если очищать с помощью subels.empty(), то они в итоге все удаляются

```js
console.log(result);
                $('.menu').empty();
                for (item of result) {
                    // console.log(item);

                    if (item['sub'] == 1) {
                        //С сабменю

                        var subels = $(`<ul></ul>`);

                        var el = $(`<li><a>${item['name']}</a></li>`);

                        for (var sub of item['subs']) {
                            subels.append(`<li><a href="${sub.href}">${sub.subname}</a></li>`);
                        }
                        el.append(subels);
                        $('.menu').append(el);

                    } else if (item['sub'] == 0) {
                        //Без сабменю
                        var el = $(`<li><a href="${item['href']}">${item['name']}</a></li>`);
                        $('.menu').append(el);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: и что? какая переменная? что не очищается?

Comment: Извините, забыл написать. Переменная subels.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте empty в начале итерации